# Playing videos from Google drive with videogular2

Tags: html5-video, videogular

I am trying to use videogular2 and I have simply replaced the static video content link with a shareable link from Google drive that points to an MP4 video file.

```
                <vg-player>
                    <video [vgMedia]="media" #media id="singleVideo" preload="auto" controls>
                        <source src="https://drive.google.com/open?id=xyz" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
                </vg-player>
```

Under Chrome browser the video player shows a resistance icon at the center and cannot play anything as it can be seen at the following screenshot:
[image: Chrome browser]

Under Internet Explorer the video player shows the text "Invalid source" and the play button on the left as it can be seen on the next image:
[image: Internet Explorer]

But if I use the sample URL: http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.mp4
it works very well.

I would appreciate any ideas/pointers related to what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and solve it using an address like the following:

`https://drive.google.com/uc?id=ID_OF_YOUR_VIDEO&export=download&authuser=0`

Comment: Just a comment @Raul Rodriguez Ruiz inside the url you wrote export=download that basically downloads the video and it does not do a streaming. I have deleted this parameter and the streaming worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for reminding me this. I found the answer long time a go but I haven't updated SO. I will accept your answer of course.

In order to view a Google video from my application (not necessarily using the Videogular plugin) I used an iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/ *** VIDEO ID *** /preview?pli=1" frameborder="0" target="_parent">
</iframe>
```

If you want to start the video from a specific time and not from start add this parameter at the video url:

```
&t=10
```

where 10 is the start time in seconds. In this case the video will start playing from the 10th second.